# Does waterglass conduct electricity?

Tags: electricity, conductors

I'm wondering if waterglass (sodium silicate) either in solution and/or dry conducts electricity?

Comment: The abstract [here](https://doi.org/10.1177/0021998306061296) seems to say so but I'm no expert

Comment: Sodium silicate itself as a solid doesn't conduct electricity. In solution yes, as there will be ions. The paper mentioned above is about a composite with graphite.

Comment: Thank you Alvhimista! Would you like to copy your comment and paste it as an answer?

Comment: @Hans not really necessary. What it goes under the umbrella term waterglass can be complicated in details. The distilled juice is that the situation here is not dissimilar to the sodium chloride case, or any other water soluble salt/ionic compound.